# How can I configure Conan to accept corp CA when using conans.tools.download()?

Tags: conan

While I'm able to get Conan to download a package from a remote by adding a corporate CA certifiate to `cacert.pem`, many of these package recipes use `conans.tools.download()` to download source code from external sites.  It seems as if this functionality does not use `cacert.pem` for its certificate store.

So, for a simple example, I have a `conanfile.txt` that looks like this:

```
[requires]
sdl2/2.0.8@bincrafters/stable
```

Of course there is no sdl2 binary for Visual Studio 2019, so I need to specify the compiler version, build type, cppstd (well, technically not this one since SDL2 is written in C), etc, but the larger project uses C++, so I run the command to build SDL2:

```
conan install .. -s compiler.version=16 -s build_type=Debug -s compiler.cppstd=17 --build
```

Conan downloads the package fine, since it's respecting the corp CA I've added to `cacert.pem`, but the package recipe uses `tools.download()` to actually pull the source.  This failed spectacularly with this error:

```
ERROR: Error downloading file https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.8.tar.gz: 'HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.libsdl.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /release/SDL2-2.0.8.tar.gz (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)'),))'
```

While I'm able to modify the recipe directly by adding `verify=False` to the download call, this is obviously not a viable solution.

How can this be fixed?  I'd prefer not to disable certification verification but at this point would settle for that.

Comment: conans.tools.download()  uses requests to download. Have you tried adding the env var REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE?  You can try any approach as solving a problem related SSL error + python requests

Comment: BTW You won't able to disable the verify parameter from that recipe. Related case: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/2460#issuecomment-365003032

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the ROOT (not a non-root ancestor) certificate in the Python `requests` package CA bundle, or create a new CA bundle that includes the root certificate and use the `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable.

Comment: Tried to set this environment variable but it does not work. My ca bundle works, putting it as cacert.pem in .conan directory is working fine. But I would like to configure a different file instead of manually overwriting files.